# Durable Functions: Error getting value from 'UsePollingFileWatcher'

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-durable-functions

This error just started ocurring out of nowhere. I have a durable function in Azure that has been running for about 6 weeks with no problem and last week started failing.

```
Error getting value from 'UsePollingFileWatcher' on 'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider'.
```

I tried it locally and got the same error. There have been absolutely no code changes between what was working and what isn't working now. I'm really stumped.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=Error getting value from 'UsePollingFileWatcher' on 'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider'.
Source=Newtonsoft.Json
StackTrace:
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ExpressionValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
at DurableTask.Core.Serializing.JsonDataConverter.Serialize(Object value, Boolean formatted)
at DurableTask.Core.Serializing.JsonDataConverter.Serialize(Object value)
at DurableTask.Core.TaskOrchestrationContext.<ScheduleTaskInternal>d__15.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at DurableTask.Core.TaskOrchestrationContext.<ScheduleTaskToWorker>d__14`1.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at DurableTask.Core.TaskOrchestrationContext.<ScheduleTask>d__13`1.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.DurableOrchestrationContext.<CallDurableTaskFunctionAsync>d__52`1.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at DGS.Interfaces.IAM.Functions.IdentityAccessManager.<OrchestrateUpdateDirectory>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\...\IAM.UpdateDirectory.cs:line 141

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Cannot modify UsePollingFileWatcher once file watcher has been initialized.
```

Comment: * Cannot modify UsePollingFileWatcher once file watcher has been initialized.* are oyou trying to modify FileWatcher?

Comment: No I have no code that does anything with FileWatcher. I assume it's in one of the Microsoft SDKs but since I haven't changed any versions I'm not sure as to why this would be happening now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The callstack indicates that the exception is being thrown when the Durable Task Framework tries to serialize some input that you're trying to send to an activity function. My guess is that the object you're sending has a complex property graph that somewhere has a pointer to a `PhysicalFileProvider`, which is not serializeable.

Check the type of object you're sending to your activity function from the `OrchestrateUpdateDirectory` method and see if it might have some extra properties that you're not expecting.

Comment: I was passing an instance of IConfigurationRoot as a parameter to an activity. I found the PhysicalFileProvider in that instance